# View vs SurfaceView for android game

Tags: android, view, surfaceview, game-engine

Some people says on SurfaceView, others on View. Which one is the best for a simple android game that uses drawable resources for its entities, and it does NOT uses OpenGL

Answer (score 3):

I'l recomend you read https://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/

Very helpfull for 2D game development and 3D games.

And book link [http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Android-Games-Mario-Zechner/dp/1430230428/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1299265138&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230428)

Comment: Thanks it's a cool article, but I just want to know where to draw the game.

Comment: In this book he explain wich cases you use View and why u need goto SurfaceView - simply. Because it has own Thread for Math calculation or background long operations.