# Handling MotionEvent on game thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing a game for android and using the following method to pass MotionEvents captured on a view to the game for processing.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    game.input(event);
    return true;
}
```

The game is updated and drawn by using the View#onDraw method:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    game.update();
    game.draw(canvas);
    this.invalidate();
}
```

As you know, android handles input and rendering on separate threads so a MotionEvent may be passed to the game while it is rendering the frame or after the logic is updated. This is not appropriate for the way I handle input in my game.

I have tried queuing the events in an ArrayList and processing them in the update method of the game. However, as expected, this causes a concurrent modification exception when clearing the queue after the items in the queue have been processed.

I would appreciate any help on how to make the queuing system work or any other method of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your problem, it is in architecture. You need to use [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html). Explore this material: http://obviam.net/index.php/a-very-basic-the-game-loop-for-android/
There is an example that you need:

[image]

Useful materials still have here:
[View vs SurfaceView for android game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071959/view-vs-surfaceview-for-android-game)